# hi, how do i convert a number into a number explicitly

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

Convert the string "42" into a number explicitly.
I have to do this in javascript. What's the conversion
[that s the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNTaa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parseInt(); function

```js
var a = parseInt("42")
console.log(a);
```